# How to make html input type numeric NOT appear as type password on apple device

Tags: html, iphone

My goal is to have my input element force the apple device to toggle a decimal-number keyboard when clicked on. I managed to do that just fine, however, when entering numbers the input element is treated as a password and the numbers are replaced with dots.

How do I make an input element tag force the apple device to show a decimal-number keyboard and NOT act as a type password input element?

I have tried the all different combinations shown in the input element below

```
             <input
                  onChange={handleInputs}
                  value={someVariable_1}
                  id={someVariable_2}
                  type="text"/"numeric"/"number"
                  autoComplete="off"
                  autoCapitalize="off"
                  autoCorrect="off"
                  pattern="[0-9]*"
                  inputMode="decimal"
                />
```

Comment: @NilsKähler just tried it in my iPhone simulator... same result :(

Comment: try to set `-webkit-text-security: none;` and `input-security: none;` in your styles.

Comment: @NilsKähler THAT did it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `type="text"` you can try some other venues, since the browser should not show it as a password. You can try 2 other methods,

1. `-webkit-text-security: none;`
2. `input-security: none;`

The first is only supported by browsers that support the webkit keyword, and the second option is still a draft and not really supported by any browsers yet. So it might be a good idea to test this in different browsers [caniuse says that -webkit-text-security](https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-text-security) is not supported by firefox for example.